# Why is this MySQL query related to dates not working

Tags: mysql

I am running a query on my phpMyAdmin but I am not getting any results, stuck on this for an hour now

**The query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `customer` 
WHERE `name` = 'DEMO' AND `date` BETWEEN 01/01/2011 AND 31/12/2012;
```

Image of structure and a record which lies within the date range

[image]

Comment: Your dates are invalid. They're just multiple numbers being divided: `01/01/2011` -> 0.00049726. MySQL dates are strings in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so you need `BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
SELECT * FROM `customer`
WHERE name = 'DEMO' and `date` between '2011-01-01' and '2012-12-31';
```

Comment: And if you want to SELECT dates to a specific format: SELECT col1, col2, DATE_FORMAT(datecolumn, '%d-%m-%Y') AS datecolumn, more1...
FROM sometable
....